# Replace Python dictionary value with new value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using the values of a file to create populate a dictionary. I created the file using a function:

```
def save_dict_to_file(filename, dictionary):  # done
    with open(filename, 'w') as w:
        for key in dictionary:
            w.write("(")
            w.write(key)
            w.write(")")
            w.write("@(")
            w.write(str(dictionary[key]))
            w.write(")")
            w.write("\n")

print (save_dict_to_file('save_dict_to_file_example.txt', {'abc':3,'def':'ghj'}))
```

Original file content:

```
(abc)@(3)
(def)@(ghj)
```

The 3 is an integer. I'd like to maintain the data type in the dictionary but currently the dictionary is returning '3' as a string:

```
{'abc': '3', 'def': 'ghj'}
```

Here is my full code:

```
def load_dict_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as r:
        dictionary = dict()
        file_contents=r.readlines()
        for line in file_contents:
            #line=line.strip()
            index=line.index('@')
            key=line[1:index-1] #before the @
            value=line[index+2:-2] #after the @
            value=value.strip()
            dictionary[key]=value
            for character in key,value:
                if character.isdigit():
                    index_character=character.index
                    new_character = int(character)
                else:
                    continue
    print(dictionary)
```

How do I delete the old character from the dictionary and replace it with the new one?

Comment: Please include example code and put the sample data in the question, not a link to a png.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help to clarify this question.

Comment: I am not familiar with the file format - either what wrote it or how its read and parsed to build a dict. Can you provide more info?

Comment: Hi @tdelaney thanks for your question, just added more context about the file format.

Comment: You can easily save objects to file using `pickle`. But doing it by hand is good training of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer what I think you're asking. Please correct me if I am misinterpreting!

I believe you're asking how can you read the numbers in your txt file as integers. Unfortunately, I don't know entirely what the purpose or structure of this file is, but I'm going to guess that it is mapping the text inside the parentheses to the left of the @ symbol to the text found inside the parentheses to the right of the @ symbol. Per your code file example, this would be `{'abc': 3, 'def': 'ghj'}`.

To do this, you could use the python string method .isdigit() and convert to int if it returns true or you could also just try except it with a ValueError if you believe that most values will be integers. Here's the two approaches:

```
# PSEUDOCODE
file_dictionary = {}
for each line in file:
    key = ...
    value = ...
    # HERE GOES SOLUTION 1 OR 2
```

SOLUTION 1:

```
if value.isdigit():
    file_dictionary[key] = int(value)
else:
    file_dictionary[key] = value
```

SOLUTION 2: (Faster if you know that most will be integers, but slower if other way around)

```
try:
    file_dictionary[key] = int(value)
except ValueError:
    file_dictionary[key] = value
```

If you are wanting to edit a dictionary value, you can just access the value you are wanting to edit and assign it to another value. Ex: `file_dictionary['abc'] = 3`
If you want to edit a key, you will have to assign the value of the new key and delete the old one. Ex:

```
file_dictionary = {'abd' = 3}  # Create the dictionary
file_dictionary['abc'] = 3  # file_dictionary now = {'abc': 3, 'abd': 3}
file_dictionary.pop('abd')  # file_dictionary now = {'abc': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope everything is going well with you during this strange times.

First, you can simplify your code to write by using formatting.

```
def save_dict_to_file(filename, dictionary):  # done
    with open(filename, 'w') as w:
    for key in dictionary:
        w.write("({})@({})\n".format(key, dictionary[key]))
```

But there are easier ways to save a dictionary in a file. You could simply write it to the file or pickle it for example.

For the loading part:

```
def load_dict_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as r:
        dictionary = {}
        file_contents = r.readlines()
        for line in file_contents:
            key, value = line.split('@')
            if key.isdigit():
                key = int(key.strip())
            if value.isdigit():
                value = int(value.strip())   
        dictionary[key]=value

    print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Updated. I think this is the simplest way to achieve what you want. Converts both key and value.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for digits on decode, but you could just try to make it an `int` and catch the exception when it fails.

```
def load_dict_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as r:
        dictionary = dict()
        file_contents=r.readlines()
        for line in file_contents:
            #line=line.strip()
            index=line.index('@')
            key=line[1:index-1] #before the @
            value=line[index+2:-2] #after the @
            value=value.strip()
            # see if its an int
            try:
                value = int(value)
            execpt ValueError:
                pass
            dictionary[key]=value
    print(dictionary)
```